# Is this MySQL-to-HQL converting correct?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

Please help. Is this MySQL syntax to HQL converting correct?

MySQL:

```
SELECT item.* FROM item, itemGroup
WHERE item.groupId = itemGroup.groupId
AND itemGroup.display = 1
ORDER BY itemGroup.displayOrder ASC
```

HQL:

```
FROM item AS I, itemGroup AS IG
WHERE I.groupId = IG.groupId
AND IG.display = 1
ORDER BY IG.displayOrder ASC
```

Thank you.

Comment: Run it and see. Hibernate could say it faster and better than community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it's not correct (except if you use - against any convention - lower case for the class names).

In HQL you do not use table names or column names from the database. Instead you use the names of the mapped classes and the getters/setters or the member variables.

Also you better only select one class and the joined class Hibernate will join automatically. It might be like this:

```
FROM Item AS i
   WHERE i.itemGroup.display = 1
   ORDER BY i.itemGroup.displayOrder ASC
```

The join between item and itemGroup you have to specify in the mapping file.
Alternatively you can use the 'inner join' clause in the HQL statement.

Comment: Thank you. You gave me very valuable advice - my query is working now.